# What is wrong in this C code ? If its a logical error please suggest the right way

Tags: c, logic

```
int i;
for(i=7;i<6;i--)//loop does not execute
{
    printf("*");
}
```

The above code should print one * but it does nothing. Shouldn'tit run same as for(i=7;i<8;i++) ?

Is this a logical error ? Please help.

Comment: When `i=7`, `i<6` is obviously false

Comment: What **isn't** wrong with this C code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `for` loop has 3 parts

```
for( init ; cond ; step )
```

When the execution reaches the loop,

1. `init` is executed.
2. `cond` is evaluated.

   - If false, break the loop
   - If true, proceed to the next step
3. Execute the body of the loop.
4. Do `step`(in many cases, this is increment/decrement)
5. Goto step 2

In your case , `i` is set to 7. Then the condition `i<6` is checked. Obviously, `7<6` is false. So the loop never gets executed.

And **No**.

```
for(i=7;i<6;i--)
```

and

```
for(i=7;i<8;i++)
```

aren't the same.

Perhaps you wanted to write

```
for(i=7;i>6;i--) //'>' instead of '<'
```

in which the loop will execute once.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the loop

```
for( i = 7 ; i < 6 ; i-- )
```

`i` is initialized `7`, but you have the condition `i < 6`, but `i` is `7`, and therefor, it does not satisfy the condition of the loop. So, the code does not even go through one iteration of the loop.

Maybe, you meant `i > 6`

Answer (score 1):

In this loop

```
for(i=7;i<6;i--)
```

at first you set i to 7 and then check whether i is less than 6. As i is equal to 7 then it is not less than 6 and the loop iterate never.

If you want that the loop would iterate one time then you should write

```
for(i=7; i > 6;i--)
```

Though with these magic numbers the loop looks strange.:) It is not clear what is the intention of the programmer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int i;
for(i=7;i<6;i--)//loop does not execute
{
    printf("*");
}
```

In first execution of this loop value of "i" is 7
 
next we have to check the condition "i<6" it is false because 7<6 is false ,then it not give any output 
 for(i=7;i<8;i++)  is different because first "i" value is 7 
then it checks condition it is i<8 (7<8)  it is true.then it executes once
 ,after that it increment from 1 (i++),
then it checks condition .then it is false because "i" is 8 
then it stops execution.